# New Basecamp API: deleted users

Tags: basecamp

In the classic Basecamp API, there is a "deleted" attribute or field in the Person model; see [reference page here](https://github.com/basecamp/basecamp-classic-api/blob/master/sections/data_reference.md#person)

Is there a corresponding attribute in the "new" Basecamp API? If not, how can I can a list of users who are no longer in the account or project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an equivalent in the new Basecamp API - making a request to [/people.json](https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api/blob/master/sections/people.md#get-people) will return all current users that the authenticated user can see.  We don't currently include deleted people - I'll pass on the suggestion :)